# Search index only part of custom content type

Tags: search

If I add a `search index  display` on all my custom types, and set visible only a few columns, those columns will only be included in the search index ?

My problem is that i have columns i don't want to index (like file names), and i don't know how to do it.

Comment: I think this is a dup, but I can't find it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search index is a view mode, but it is hidden by default (for some unknown reason).

Goto the **Manage Display** page for your content type.  Expand the **Custom Display Settings** at the bottom.  Tick **Search Index** and save.

A new tab, **Search Index** will appear.  Click this, and then configure your content type to show / hide the fields you want indexed.

You may need to dump the search index (admin/config/search/settings) and then reindex the site.  I can't recall if saving the search index does this automatically, of if I normally form alter that form to do it.  The easiest way to do this is with drush:

```
drush -y search-reindex
drush -y search-index
```

As a side note, I will be releasing a small module to help debug search issues and check things like this.  I am test driving it on a few sites now, and think it will be ready soon.

Comment: So, if i enable the `search index` display view and set it how i want, only what i set visible will be indexed ?

Comment: @rhose87 Yes, that should work for you.  I will update the answer if/when I release the module.